# How to restrict Tensorflow's weights tensor has same row variable? means under updating,still keep same

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

I have a stupid question, but I don't know how to slove it.

I have a neural network designed by tensorflow， it has several weights matrix .

My output layer is a fully connected network, and it has a 2D weights matrix W.

assume W is a 3x3 matrix, my algorithm need W's row value are same. means under the updating procedure, W changes to W', but each row's elements changed simultaneously and keeps same value:

```
W=                          W'=
 [[ x,x,x],                  [[ x',x',x'],
  [ y,y,y],    ->             [ y',y',y'],
  [ z,z,z]]                   [ z',z',z']]
```

means after each training step, x and y,z changes to x',y',z'.   but all of 1st row's elements are x'. For 2nd and 3rd row, the rule are same.

So, how do define or set this W matrix (or 2D-tensor) in tensorflow ? thank u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Onw way would be to define your weights as a single row and use `tf.tile` to repeat it for the matrix multiplication. So for example instead of

```
W = tf.get_variable("weights", shape=[3, 3])
outputs = tf.matmul(inputs, W)
```

you would use

```
W = tf.get_variable("weights", shape=[3, 1])
outputs = tf.matmul(inputs, tf.tile(W, [1, 3]))
```

this will create a variable that looks like `[[x], [y], [z]]`, and the `tile` command simply replicates it over several columns. Unfortunately you won't be able to use functions like `tf.layers.dense` this way, but sometimes we need to sacrifice some convenience if we want flexibility.

Note that depending on what exactly you are doing with this matrix there might be more efficient ways that avoid the explicit tiling by making use of different tensor multiplication methods. The above example covers a standard fully-connected layer.